# read data values from firebase Realtime database

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

These are the values read by sensor

[image]

Im trying to fetch these values from this database and use them in my application developed using flutter. But idk how. Any help is appreciated. language used is dart. I need to read four different values to four different variables

I tried many ways but ends up in error. i got one code thats not showing error but dont seem to read value

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Sensor');

class Fetch {
  void getData() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/');
    ref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      var temp = event.snapshot.value;
      print(temp);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You `temp` is returning correct data as map on my case

Comment: @YeasinSheikh So, the temp variable maps every value in the database, right? What should I do if I need only one value? say, the value of dht11 to temp

Comment: You need to cast as Map , then you can get read with key as shown on answer section

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but it works fine for me in this zapp.run: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-za2406oha250 (check the logs to see the value from the database

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
```

**without listen:**

```
DatabaseReference refer = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/');

await refer.get().then((DataSnapshot data) async {
        print ( (data.value! as Map) ['gas'] ) 
                       ...
```

**with listen:**

```
refer.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final Object? data = event.snapshot.value;
      print( (data as Map)['gas'] )
                 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Stream from `FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/').onValue;` and use `StreamBuilder` to display data. and you can separate the logic from UI code.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late final stream = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/').onValue;

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/');
          await ref.set({
            'dht11': 32 + counter++,
            'gas': 1152,
            'humidity': 71,
            'pressure': 1111.111,
          });
        },
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final data = snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
                if (data == null) {
                  return Text('No data');
                }
                final dht11 = data['dht11'];
                final gas = data['gas'];
                final humidity = data['humidity'];
                final pressure = data['pressure'];
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('dht11: $dht11'),
                    Text('gas: $gas'),
                    Text('humidity: $humidity'),
                    Text('pressure: $pressure'),
                  ],
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(snapshot.error.toString());
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              }

              return Text('....');
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, to structure your db, you should use `sensors` instead of `Sensor`. Lowercase and plural. See more about structure data in Firebase Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/structure-data
2. Some remarks on your code:

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('Sensor'); <-- why do you define this without using it? 

class Fetch {
  void getData() { <-- getData function does not have returned value, so when you call it, even it has data, you cannot retrieve them. 
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Sensor/'); <-- and you redefine ref here
    ref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      var temp = event.snapshot.value;
      print(temp);
    });
  }
}
```

3. Data returned from Firebase Realtime DB will be viewed as Map in Flutter, so to access data, you will need to pass `data as Map`.

- Use with listen:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("sensors");
ref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value as Map;
});
```

- Use with async await:

  - Use with get():

  ```
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await ref.child('sensors/$sensorId').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
      final data = snapshot.value as Map;
  } else {
      print('No data available.');
  }
  ```

  - Use with once():

  ```
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("sensors");
  final event = await ref.once(DatabaseEventType.value);
  final data = event.snapshot.value as Map;
  ```